# Determine index of ng-repeat element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm wondering if there is a way to determine the index when processing a ng-repeat.

For example, I only want the first and second indexs to have anchor tags in the following:

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in rows | orderBy:sort.type:sort.reverse | filter:searchData">
        <!-- only want to make the index 0 and 1 have an anchor -->
        <td ng-repeat="column in cols"><a href="#">{{row[column]}}</a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I'm thinking something like the following is needed, but I can't figure out (or find) the proper syntax:

```
<!-- if index == 0 or 1, show anchor -->
<td ng-repeat="column in cols" ng-if="row[$index] <2"><a href="#">{{row[column]}}</a></td>

<!-- else, if index >= 2, don't show anchor -->
<td ng-repeat="column in cols" ng-if="row[$index] >=2">{{row[column]}}</td>
```

Here is a fiddle with a base example: https://jsfiddle.net/zp2cqxqb/

Thanks for any assistance with this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are interested in the $index itself, rather than the row[$index] value, as you are currently checking.

As a bonus, if you make use of another inline element, such as a span, for the non-anchor value, you can avoid a double ng-repeat statement:

```
 <tr ng-repeat="row in rows | orderBy:sort.type:sort.reverse | filter:searchData">
    <!-- only want to make the index 0 and 1 have an anchor -->
    <td ng-repeat="column in cols">
      <a ng-if="$index < 2" href="#">{{row[column]}}</a>
      <span ng-if="$index >= 2">{{row[column]}}</span>
    </td>
 </tr>
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z87ntjne/

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks much!